# QLabels with setWordWrap(True) are not resizing vertically when placed in a QListWidget, even though resizeMode has been set to Adjust

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlabel, qlistwidget

**How can i put `QLabel`s with `setWordWrap(True)` inside of a `QListWidget`/`QListView` so that the `QLabel`s are resized correctly when the parent widget is resized?**

When i have tried to do this i have ran into problems with the QLabels not getting the right height (see example 2 below)

I'm using

- Python: 3.8.5
- PyQt5: 5.15.2

### Example 1: Using a `QVBoxLayout`

To show what i would like to accomplish i want to start by showing an example where i am simply adding `QLabel`s to a QVBoxLayout

*This works as i had hoped: If i resize the (main) window horizontally the `QLabel` with wrapped text will take up more space vertically*

[image: example 1]

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setMinimumHeight(150)
        self.main_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.main_widget.setLayout(vbox)

        label_1 = QLabel("label_1")
        vbox.addWidget(label_1)
        label_1.setStyleSheet("*{background-color: #f0f000;}")

        label_2 = QLabel("[wrapped] label_2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.")
        vbox.addWidget(label_2)
        label_2.setStyleSheet("*{background-color: #00f0f0;}")
        label_2.setWordWrap(True)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
main_window = MainWindow()
main_window.show()
app.exec_()
```

### Example 2: Using a `QListWidget`

*This is the code that i am having problems with: Running this code doesn't give any extra space for the `Qlabel`s with wrapped text*

(`QListWidget` has been used in the example instead of `QListView` but from what i have seen - and from what i understand of these classes - there shouldn't be a difference)

Please note that the [resizeMode property](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistview.html#resizeMode-prop) has been set to `QListView.Adjust`

[image: example 2]

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.list_widget = QListWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.list_widget)
        self.list_widget.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.list_widget.setResizeMode(QListView.Adjust)  # <-----
        self.list_widget.setUniformItemSizes(False)  # -should already be false, but just in case
        self.list_widget.setWordWrap(True)  # -AFAIK this should only effect text that is put directly into QListWidgetItems, but just in case

        item_1_text_str = f"Item number 1"
        lwi_item_1 = QListWidgetItem(self.list_widget)
        self.list_widget.addItem(lwi_item_1)
        item_1_widget_qlabel = QLabel(item_1_text_str)
        item_1_widget_qlabel.setStyleSheet("*{background-color: #f0f000;}")
        self.list_widget.setItemWidget(lwi_item_1, item_1_widget_qlabel)

        item_2_text_str = "[wrapped] label_2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
        lwi_item_2 = QListWidgetItem(self.list_widget)
        self.list_widget.addItem(lwi_item_2)
        item_widget_2_qlabel = QLabel(item_2_text_str)
        item_widget_2_qlabel.setWordWrap(True)  # <-------
        item_widget_2_qlabel.setStyleSheet("*{background-color: #00f0f0;}")
        self.list_widget.setItemWidget(lwi_item_2, item_widget_2_qlabel)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
main_window = MainWindow()
main_window.show()
app.exec_()
```

### What i've tried

#### Setting the size policy to `Expanding`

Normally the policy is set to `MinimumExpanding`, so i figured `Expanding` would be better since `Expanding` includes the `Shrink` flag

In code example 2 above it would look like this:

```
    item_widget_2_qlabel.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
```

This didn't help though

#### Using the `sizeHint` from the `QLabel` to set the size hint of the QListWidgetItem

If done in `__init__`:

`lwi_item_2.setSizeHint(item_widget_2_qlabel.sizeHint())`

The problem with this is that it will just set the size hint once and then the sizeHint will be stuck, so the QLabel with wrapped text cannot expand or contract vertically

Alternatively using this code so that the sizeHint is updated when the main window is resized:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    [...]

def resizeEvent(self, a0: QResizeEvent) -> None:
    super().resizeEvent(a0)
    row = 0
    while row < self.list_widget.count():
        lwi_item = self.list_widget.item(row)
        item_widget = self.list_widget.itemWidget(lwi_item)
        widget_size_hint = item_widget.sizeHint()
        lwi_item.setSizeHint(widget_size_hint)  # <--------
        row += 1
```

Surprisingly the result when using this code is the same: The vertical size of the QLabel doesn't change

Comment: Why do you need to use a QListWidget *and* QLabels?

Comment: @musicamante Hi and thank you for the question. I'm using `QListWidget`/`QListView` in several projects i'm working on, one typical reason i want to put the `QLabel` there is because i have a custom row/item widget (added using `setItemWidget`) holding two or three other widgets, one of which is a `QLabel` with text that i want to wrap --- I'm open to using other approaches though so if you know of good alternatives please share!

Comment: Well, QLabel is a bit peculiar, as it's the only widget that has its own way of dealing with sizes, due to its nature of being able to adapt its contents based on the available space (and, partially, vice versa). Given what you described, I can understand the need for this approach, and the solution proposed in your answer seems acceptable to me: the reason for the resizeEvent implementation of the question not working is that the sizeHint returned by the label is based on the horizontal available space given by the listview as soon as it's mapped.

Comment: @musicamante Okay, that makes sense, thank you for taking the time to comment and explain. I've been using PyQt for a couple of years now but it's first now that i am starting to learn it for real. One thing that confuses me though is that `setResizeMode(QListView.Adjust)` doesn't seem to do anything, is this then only effective for other types of widgets? https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistview.html#resizeMode-prop

Answer (score 0):

While writing this question i was able to find a solution using `QLabel.heightForWidth` inside a overridden `resizeEvent` of a `QListWidget` subclass

It's not what i was hoping for though (i had hoped that i had missed something simple so that the solution would be more elegant). ***If anyone has a better solution than this please share!***

Anyway here is the code i used to get it working

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class ListWidget(QListWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        """
        self.list_widget.setResizeMode(QListView.Adjust)
        -this is not needed with this solution. (Maybe because it only effects QListWidgetItems?)
        """

    def resizeEvent(self, a0: QResizeEvent) -> None:
        super().resizeEvent(a0)
        row = 0
        while row < self.count():
            lwi_item = self.item(row)
            item_widget = self.itemWidget(lwi_item)
            if isinstance(item_widget, QLabel) and hasattr(item_widget, "wordWrap") and item_widget.wordWrap():
                width_int = self.width() - self.contentsMargins().left() - self.contentsMargins().right()
                height_hfw_int = item_widget.heightForWidth(width_int)  # <--------
                widget_size_hint = QSize(width_int, height_hfw_int)
                lwi_item.setSizeHint(widget_size_hint)
            row += 1


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.list_widget = ListWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.list_widget)

        lwi_item_1 = QListWidgetItem(self.list_widget)
        self.list_widget.addItem(lwi_item_1)
        item_1_widget_qlabel = QLabel("Item number 1")
        item_1_widget_qlabel.setStyleSheet("*{background-color: #f0f000;}")
        self.list_widget.setItemWidget(lwi_item_1, item_1_widget_qlabel)

        lwi_item_2 = QListWidgetItem(self.list_widget)
        self.list_widget.addItem(lwi_item_2)
        item_2_html_rich_str = "<span style='font-size:12pt'>Listen, strange women lyin in ponds distributin swords is no basis for a system of government.</span><br><span>Supreme executive power derives from a mandate from the masses, not from some farcical aquatic ceremony.</span>"
        item_2_markdown_str = "## Listen, strange women lyin in ponds distributin swords is no basis for a system of government.\n\nSupreme executive power derives from a mandate from the masses, not from some farcical aquatic ceremony."
        item_2_text_str = "Listen, strange women lyin in ponds distributin swords is no basis for a system of government.\n\nSupreme executive power derives from a mandate from the masses, not from some farcical aquatic ceremony."
        item_widget_2_qlabel = QLabel(item_2_html_rich_str)
        item_widget_2_qlabel.setTextFormat(Qt.RichText)  # Qt.RichText, Qt.MarkdownText, Qt.PlainText
        item_widget_2_qlabel.setWordWrap(True)  # <-------
        item_widget_2_qlabel.setStyleSheet("*{background-color: #00f0f0;}")
        self.list_widget.setItemWidget(lwi_item_2, item_widget_2_qlabel)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
main_window = MainWindow()
main_window.show()
app.exec_()
```